# Why does the histogram object get printed when hist is called in j?

Tags: r, data.table

```
set.seed(120834)
DT <- data.table(var = rnorm(100))
```

Compare:

```
> hist(DT[ , var]) #of course plot is drawn
```

With

```
> DT[ , hist(var)]
$breaks
 [1] -3.0 -2.5 -2.0 -1.5 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5

$counts
 [1]  1  1  6  7 16 20 20 12 12  3  2

$density
 [1] 0.02 0.02 0.12 0.14 0.32 0.40 0.40 0.24 0.24 0.06 0.04

$mids
 [1] -2.75 -2.25 -1.75 -1.25 -0.75 -0.25  0.25  0.75  1.25  1.75  2.25

$xname
[1] "var"

$equidist
[1] TRUE

attr(,"class")
[1] "histogram"
```

Why does the latter print the object returned by `hist`, but not the former? Is there a way to suppress this?

I'm seeing in the code for `hist.default` that the object is returned invisibly:

```
if (plot) {
        plot(r, freq = freq1, col = col, border = border, angle = angle, 
            density = density, main = main, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, 
            xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, axes = axes, labels = labels, 
            ...)
        invisible(r)
    }
```

(And looking at the error from `DT[ , hist(var, NA)]` confirms `[.data.table` is indeed invoking `hist.default`)

So how did `[.data.table` manage to supercede this invisible return call? Is it perhaps that the invisible object is returned to a hidden environment invisibly, but the object from that environment is then returned visibly?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jaap Mainly satisfying curiousity. But it is annoying to have the clutter in my console every time I call `hist` within `j` (which feels more natural to me); so a way to suppress that output without wrapping `invisible(DT[,hist(var)])` would be nice

Comment: And I'm thinking now this is basically a feature request, since it seems I've figured out what's going on -- an invisible object is returned to an invisible environment, but the next environment doesn't inherit/recognize this and hence returns the object visibly. I'm sort of surprised that `with(DT, hist(var))` doesn't suffer the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, and, as of now, there's no known solution or plans to fix it.

See [GH Issue #482](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/482) for updates.

---

## Edit from Matt -- Workarounds

You can suppress it like this :

```
DT[ , {hist(var);NULL}]
```

or

```
invisible(DT[,hist(var)])
```

Looks like we need to revisit this as FAQ 2.18 needs an update: "2.18 I’m using j for its side effect only, but I’m still getting data returned. How do I stop that?"  I have *tried* to better in the past, spending several man days on it. We are limited by R internals to some extent (as FAQ 2.22 explains)